# Descargar Fichero usando PHP

Tags: php, variables, qrcode

Deseo descargar un una imagen del servidor mediante PHP. 
Especificaciones:

- No deseo usar javascript y tampoco quiero pasar por base de datos el nombre para luego recuperarlo.
- La imagen que deseo descargar es un código QR que he generado y que he guardado en un directorio "php_action/temp". Dentro e este directorio hay varias imágenes, por lo que estoy intentando descargar solo el fichero que he generado.
- He añadido la librería phpqrcode y he creado un archivo que llama a dicha librería para generar el código QR. Este archivo es show_product2.php en root.

  ```
   //set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files

    session_start();

  $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  //html PNG location prefix
  $PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

  include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

  //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
  if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
  mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


  $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';

  //processing form input
  //remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
  $errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
  if (isset($_REQUEST['level']) && in_array($_REQUEST['level'], 
  array('L','M','Q','H')))
  $errorCorrectionLevel = $_REQUEST['level'];

  $matrixPointSize = 4;
  if (isset($_REQUEST['size']))
  $matrixPointSize = min(max((int)$_REQUEST['size'], 1), 10);


  if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {

  //it's very important!
  if (trim($_REQUEST['data']) == '')
      die('Introduzca la Referencia del Producto en el campo "Referencia" 
  y haga clic en "Generar", no puede dejar en blanco los datos! <a href="?">Regresar</a>');
    $ReferenciaProducto = $_REQUEST['data'];
  // user data
  $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.$ReferenciaProducto.'-'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
  QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);


     $filename2 = $ReferenciaProducto.'-'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
  $_SESSION['filename']=$filename2; 

  } else {

   //default data
  echo 'La Imagen QR que aparece por defecto, es de prueba, hasta que no introduzca la referncia en el campo inferior y presione "Generar" no se visualizará la imagen definitiva"<hr/>';
  QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);

    }

   //display generated file
  // echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
   echo '<img src="'.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';

  //.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

  //config form
  echo '<form action="show_product2.php" method="post">
  Ref:&nbsp;<input name="data" value="'.(isset($_REQUEST['data'])? 
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['data']):'Escriba  Ref.de Producto').'" />&nbsp;
  Definición:&nbsp;<select name="level">
      <option value="L"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='L')?' selected':'').'>L 
  - Muy Baja</option>
      <option value="M"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='M')?' selected':'').'>Baja</option>
      <option value="Q"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='Q')?' selected':'').'>Media</option>
      <option value="H"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='H')?' selected':'').'>Alta - La Mejor</option>
  </select>&nbsp;
  Tamaño:&nbsp;<select name="size">';

   for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.(($matrixPointSize==$i)?' selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>';

  echo '</select>&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="GENERAR"></form><hr/>';


  ?>
        <center>

  <?php echo "<form method='get' action='php_action/downloadQr.php? Descargar='".$_SESSION['filename'].">";?>

  echo' <button class="btn btn-default button3" data-toggle="submit"
  name="Descargar" data-target = "Descarga"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-
   download-alt"></i> Descargar Qr en su Computadora </button>

    &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default button3" data-toggle="submit"
  id="GuardarQRlBtn" data-target="#GuardarQRlBtn"> <i class="glyphicon
  glyphicon-tasks"></i> Guardar Qr en el Servidor </button></form>';


         </center>
  ```

HE creado en otro directorio una función que es llamada para decargar el archivo. Esta función se encuentre en "includes/functions.php. YA que en el código anterior es llamada esta función mediante :"**includes/functions.php**";

```
    function descargar($fichero){

    $basefichero = basename($fichero);
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fichero));
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=" .$basefichero."");
    readfile($fichero);
      }
```

Esta es la pantalla interface, cuando se pone la referencia del producto y de presiona "Generar", el código funciona bien, pues crea el QR le da un nombre seguido de una extensión aleatoria y lo guarda en mi directorio "temp" con formato png. Como se ve en la imagen, he puesto un punto de control que fuerza al programa a escribir la referencia de la imagen que se guarda dentro de la variable "$filename2" en el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene cuando una vez he generado la imagen. que en principio creo que se guarda en la variable junto con su path "$filename" y en nombre del archivo como he dicho en "$filename2" y le presiono al botón "Descargar QR en su Computadora" el programa va a buscar el archivo dónde está las instrucciones para llamar la función de descargar que es el archivo **(deleteQrTemp.php):**

```
   <?php
    session_start();
     include "includes/functions.php";

    if(isset($_GET['Descargar'])) {

    echo $_SESSION['filename'];

     descargar($_SESSION['filename']);


       }

     ?>
```

Como método de control he puesto en este archivo la instrucción "echo $_SESSION['filename'];" para que me impresione el nombre del archivo que ahora se guarda en la variable global "$_SESSION" ya en el anterior archivo "show_product2.php" había creado para el nombre del archivo de imagen "$filename2". Y efectivamente se recibe el nombre del archivo en la variable, por tanto, hasta aquí todo bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Va al archivo, y empieza a recorrer las instrucciones, imprime de nuevo en mi "echo" de control el nombre del archivo de la imagen, eso quiere decir que la recibe, pero aquí se para, ya queda la pantalla en blanco con el nombre del archivo pero no descarga el archivo. Por tanto creo, que por eliminación, el error debe estar en la función **"descargar()"** pero no en que falla. Está fgunción la he descrito arriba.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crear un nuevo download.php?Descargar=filename
al principio del archivo colocamos un session_start();
luego

```
   <?php
session_start();
   include "includes/functions.php";
   if(isset($_GET['descarga'])) {
    descargar($filename);
    }
    ?>
```

en el primero:

```
<?php
//para que el nombre siempre quede guardo
session_start();

//set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
 $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

//html PNG location prefix
$PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

//ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


$filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';

//processing form input
//remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
$errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
if (isset($_REQUEST['level']) && in_array($_REQUEST['level'], 
array('L','M','Q','H')))
$errorCorrectionLevel = $_REQUEST['level'];

$matrixPointSize = 4;
if (isset($_REQUEST['size']))
$matrixPointSize = min(max((int)$_REQUEST['size'], 1), 10);


if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {

//it's very important!
if (trim($_REQUEST['data']) == '')
    die('Introduzca la Referencia del Producto en el campo "Referencia" 
y haga clic en "Generar", no puede dejar en blanco los datos! <a href="?">Regresar</a>');
  $ReferenciaProducto = $_REQUEST['data'];
// user data
$filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.$ReferenciaProducto.'-'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
$_SESSION["filename"] = $filename;
QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);

} else {

 //default data
echo 'La Imagen QR que aparece por defecto, es de prueba, hasta que no introduzca la referncia en el campo inferior y presione "Generar" no se visualizará la imagen definitiva"<hr/>';
QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);

  }

 //display generated file
// echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
 echo '<img src="'.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';

//.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

//config form
echo '<form action="show_product2.php" method="post">
Ref:&nbsp;<input name="data" value="'.(isset($_REQUEST['data'])? 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['data']):'Escriba  Ref.de Producto').'" />&nbsp;
Definición:&nbsp;<select name="level">
    <option value="L"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='L')?' selected':'').'>L 
- Muy Baja</option>
    <option value="M"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='M')?' selected':'').'>Baja</option>
    <option value="Q"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='Q')?' selected':'').'>Media</option>
    <option value="H"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='H')?' selected':'').'>Alta - La Mejor</option>
</select>&nbsp;
Tamaño:&nbsp;<select name="size">';

 for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.(($matrixPointSize==$i)?' selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>';

echo '</select>&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="GENERAR"></form><hr/>';


?>
  <center>        


   <?php
//validamos que el nombre del archivo exista en la varible de session

   if(isset($_SESSION["filename"])) {
      echo "<form method='get' action='download.php?descarga='".$_SESSION["filename"].">";

echo' <button class="btn btn-default button3" data-toggle="submit" 
name="Descargar" data-target = "Descarga"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
  download-alt"></i> Descargar Qr en su Computadora </button>

  &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default button3" data-toggle="submit" 
id="GuardarQRlBtn" data-target="#GuardarQRlBtn"> <i class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-tasks"></i> Guardar Qr en el Servidor </button></form>';
    ?>
</center>
```

Comment: Hola Bryro. He probado tu proposición, pero no recoge la variable "$filename", La Url  queda "http://qr-inventario.com/prueba/php_action/downloadQr.php?descarga="

Comment: en tu ejemplo el action para el form apunta otra ruta:
mira el ejemplo completo!

Comment: Hola Bryro. He re-editado mi pregunta añadiendo tu proposición, utilizando la "session_start()" y todo funciona bien, había un error en al llamar el nombre del archivo, pues estaba llamando el path completo y no el nombre del archivo de la imagen, pero ya he creado el "$filename2" dónde ahora sí, se guarda el nombre del archivo. Pero el problema está en la función "descargar() como explico en mi pregunta, Recibe el nombre del archivo correctamente, pero no ejecuta la descarga,

Answer (score 0):

Cuando pulsas el boton Descarga, se lanza el formulario que lo engloba, y te lleva al mismo archivo que estas ejecutando. Se esta recargando toda la pagina, y aunque en ese momento `Descargar` esta definido, NO SE ENVIAN las cabeceras de archivo que tienes en la funcion descargar(), puesto que ya se han enviado las de html que forman tu pagina web.

Te sugiero 2 formas:

**Que la accion de descargar esté en otro archivo:**

genera un archivo (por ej: `downloadQr.php`) con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php
  include "includes/functions.php";
  $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
  if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
      mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);

  $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';
  if(isset($_GET['Descargar'])) {
    descargar($filename);
  }
?>
```

y en tu formulario que contiene la llamada del boton Descargar, cambia el action hacia este nuevo archivo. Algo como:

```
  <form method="get" action="downloadQr.php">

 <button class="btn btn-default button3" data-toggle="submit" 
name="Descargar" data-target = "Descarga"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
  download-alt"></i> Descargar Qr en su Computadora </button>
</form>
```

Con esto, cuando pulses el boton Descargar, se llama a la accion de descargar del archivo en downloadQr.php. Se enviaran las cabeceras que defines en la funcion, y te descargará el archivo.

**Gestiona la llamada de descarga al principio de tu archivo:**
Cambia la gestion de crear el archivo, hacia el principio de tu codigo. Pon lo primero del todo esto:

```
<?php
  include "includes/functions.php";
  $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php_action'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
  if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
      mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);

  $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';
  if(isset($_GET['Descargar'])) {
    descargar($filename);
  } else {
 ?>
```

date cuenta que he puesto un `else`, esto es para que primero se vea si esta definido descargar y SOLO haga la descarga (enviando las cabeceras de archivo).
Este else deberás cerrarlo al final de tu archivo, para que, si no se ha pedido descargar el QR, que te muestre el resto de tu accion.

MI RECOMENDACION:

Todo este problema te surge porque mezclas html y proceso de php, y no esta muy claro (y se ve dificil) organizar estas cosas. Te recomendaria que empieces a utilizar MVC, revisar o utilizar algun framework (tipo symfony, codeigniter, laravel) para ver como se organizan los procesos en controladores y vistas.

Comment: Es cierto, la propuesta que planteas la entiendo perfectamente, el crear el archivo "downloadQr.php" para separarlo del archivo principal "shwo_product2.php" y desde downloadQr.php la función descargar es mucho más racional y lógica. Pero la segunfa parte del problema, es que no envía el nombre del archivo, "$filename", y en el URL superior, dice:"qr-inventario.com/prueba/php_action/downloadQr.php?Descargar= " por lo que no está enviando el valor de la variable. –

Comment: tienes razón, había omitido esa parte. Solo hay que reorganizar un poco el código en la parte superior. He editado la solución para que te defina el nombre del directorio y el del archivo.